# box-api override embedded viewer to view html

Tags: html, box-api

Is there a way to share a complex HTML file with box? Currently when I share an HTML5 file it opens in the embedded viewer and it is not rendered correctly. It would be great if I could share a file that could be responsively rendered on all devices without the need for it to be on a hosting site.

Answer (score 0):

For paid Box.com accounts only, you can use a direct link as outlined here:

https://support.box.com/hc/en-us/articles/200519908-Direct-Linking

Unfortunately, with a complex HTML file as you're describing, it may not render properly anyway depending on the browser/device, since the file is downloaded as an attachment and not viewed in the browser via box.com.

Comment: I'd like the built-in Box viewer to be able to natively render an HTML document. Is it not able to do this because of security risks?

Comment: Correct.  Box Preview renders HTML to PDF and then converts it back to HTML for the on-screen preview.  Obviously that strips out any script or interaction, and renders much CSS useless.  Box will not allow HTML to be sent straight to the browser; that's why a direct link opens as an attachment.  I had the same need go unfulfilled.  Dropbox can do it via shared folders.